# JavaScript email validation form not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have started learning JavaScript on w3Schools. I tried to execute one of the examples given in that site. For some reason I couldn't make it work. Hope it is not duplicated question. I am not getting the alert message. Let me know if there is any mistake as this is my first step in learning process.

**Edit: I corrected the code. Thanks for the help. As mentioned I forgot to close the if block. Hope one will not down vote further.**

### Edited Code:

**JS**

```
function validate() {
  //A simple mail validation function. Checks only period and '@'.
  var email = document.forms['loginForm']['email'].value;
  var period = email.lastIndexOf('.');
  var atPosition= email.indexOf('@');
  if (period < 1 || period + 2 > email.length || atPosition!= email.lastIndexOf('@')) {
    alert('Please enter a valid email address');
    return false;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action='verify.do' id="loginForm" method='post' name='loginForm'
onsubmit='return validate()'>
    E-Mail: <input autofocus="" name='email' type='text'><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Kindly let me know why you are down voting. I can improve the question.

Comment: that `if`condition sentence looks awfully written to me

Comment: w3schools is not a good source to learn javascript from. It would be better if you learn from here: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Comment: Your validation returns `undefined` when it "passes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the closing `)` here:

```
if (period < 1 || period + 2 > email.length || period != email.lastIndexOf('@') {
```

Instead, it should be:

```
if (period < 1 || period + 2 > email.length || period != email.lastIndexOf('@')) {
```

In addition, you should probably add server-side validation since this could easily be bypassed.

Also, as a side note, there are one too many of the letter `s` in your alert:

`alert('Please enter a valid email addresss');` => `alert('Please enter a valid email address');`